# Node & Backbone site hosted on Openshift not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, cross-browser, openshift

We have this site that is a node & backbone based site and for some reason the site is working perfectly fine on google chrome, but is not fully functioning on firefox. Well the issue is slightly more complicated. It ALWAYS works the first time in firefox when we go on the site after a git push, and then it subsequently fails if we try and refresh the page.

We have put console logs everywhere to try and debug the problem. We have noticed that our backbone router gets hit fine and its initialize function gets hit as well. However, the problem is that our home route("") never actually is getting hit in firefox whereas it gets hit in chrome.

Another difference from chrome to firefox is that if we watch the network in chrome, all of the resources we load in our index.html file are properly loaded. When watching the network in firefox, none of our backbone views, or models are ever loaded.

Furthermore, the site works FINE in either browser when we navigate to it using the URL provided to us by openshift. The problems only arise when we are using our actual URL.

I tried to describe the problem w/o using any code, but if I need to, I will.